# What is the population of Romulus in the TNG era?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

I'd love to know what's the Romulan population in general or on Romulus itself in the TNG era.

Comment: Memory alpha says 18 billion around 2378, but no sources are given. Also, I couldn't find anything else at the moment.

Answer (score 12):

According to the [Star Trek: Star Charts](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Star_Charts) factbook, the population of Romulus in the year 2368 is approximately 18 billion.

[image]

No information exists to describe the total number of Romulans in the galaxy, but their empire encompasses several [colony worlds](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Romulan_planets), each with potentially billions-strong populations of their own.

---

After its destruction in 2387 (about ten years after the events of *[Star Trek: Nemesis](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Nemesis)*), the population of Romulus dropped to (approximately) zero.

[image]

Comment: In the Kelvin time line, Romulus was still around? It was in the original time line that Romulus was destroyed?

Comment: Aren't they eventually destroyed in both? Wasn't it a natural disaster that destroyed Romulus, and won't that natural disaster still happen, but now without the Vulcans to try and avert it?

Comment: @coteyr - A few months ago I would have argued with you that it wasn't clear however it seems the new Picard series (set in the original timeline) will also feature the destruction of Romulus

Comment: In the Kelvin time line Romulus isn't due to be destroyed for more than a century and with that much forewarning they can doubtless save it.

Comment: @Valorum I thought the new Picard series is supposed to be in the original timeline. Example article claiming so: https://redshirtsalwaysdie.com/2019/01/12/star-trek-picard-prime-timeline-series/

Comment: @jpmc26  -Indeed, which proves that the destruction of Romulus did occur in the original timeline.

Comment: I thought the claim in question was whether it's destroyed in the Kelvin timeline.

Comment: @jpmc26 - I believe they were taking me to task for saying that the destruction is depicted as occurring in the Kelvin Timeline when it actually occurred in Spock's flashback *from the Original Timeline*.

Comment: @jim 's comment seems to be raising the question of whether the population drop ever occurred in the Kelvin timeline, since Romulus may not have been destroyed in it.

Comment: @jpmc26 - Who knows? We haven't got that far yet. We're still mucking around in the TOS era

Comment: This is why I hate time travel.